# What is volatile variable in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

What is volatile attribute of a Variable in Pytorch? Here's a sample code for defining a variable in PyTorch.

```
datatensor = Variable(data, volatile=True)
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Basically, set the input to a network to volatile if you are doing inference only and won't be running backpropagation in order to conserve memory.

From the [docs](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html#volatile):

> Volatile is recommended for purely inference mode, when you’re sure
>   you won’t be even calling .backward(). It’s more efficient than any
>   other autograd setting - it will use the absolute minimal amount of
>   memory to evaluate the model. volatile also determines that
>   requires_grad is False.

Edit: The volatile keyword has been [deprecated](http://pytorch.org/2018/04/22/0_4_0-migration-guide.html) as of pytorch version 0.4.0

Answer (score 9):

For versions of `Pytorch` previous to 0.4.0, `Variable` and `Tensor` were two different entities.  For variables, you could specify two flags: `volatile` and `require_grad`.  Both of them were used for fine grained exclusion of subgraphs from gradient computation.

The difference between `volatile` and `requires_grad` is in how the flag is applied to the outputs of an operation.  If there is even a single `volatile = True` Variable as input to an operation, its output is also going to be marked as `volatile`.  For `requires_grad`, you need all the inputs to that operation to be flagged `requires_grad = False`, so that the output is also flagged in the same way.

From `Pytorch` 0.4.0, `Tensors` and `Variables` have merged, and the `volatile` flag is deprecated.